# How to remove the cookies properly when user logs out of the session?

Tags: authentication, cookies, amazon-cognito

**Background:**

For authentication, we are using AWS Cognito. Our project contains an API server and a web server. On the client-side, when the user login to the application, we send the username & password to the cognito instance which returns a JWT access token. We set the access token in the cookies and redirect the user to the homepage. On the http server side, on each request for a private page, we check the cookie and validate the JWT access token. Similarly on the API side, for each request, we check the cookie and validate the access token.

When a user log out from the application, we remove the cookie and signout from cognito. Here is the code for removing the cookie -

```
function clearCookie(name: string, domain: string, path: string) {
  const derivedDomain = domain || document.domain;
  const derivedPath = path || "/";
  document.cookie = `${name}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; domain=${derivedDomain}; path=${derivedPath}`;
};
```

**Problem:**

The problem occurs when a user presses the back button of the browser after signing out. It seems like when the user presses the back button, the page is restored from the cache along with the cookies. And since the JWT access token is still valid, after user presses the back button they can still make the api calls and navigate the application.

Is there any way to solve this problem? How can i remove the cookie so that pressing back button will not restore the cookie? Any other authentication workflow i should use to overcome this problem?

Comment: Why not make the JWT Access Token expire on the server-side on logout

Comment: A browser cached page doesn't restore cookies. Check to see if your cookie is marked httponly. If so, you won't be able to clear it with this client-side js. In this case, you'll need the log out HTTP request to respond with a Set-Cookie header that clears the cookie.

Comment: @StephenCrosby It is not a httpOnly cookie. If the browser don't restore the cookie from the cache, then why do you think it's getting restored?

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov There are only 3 possibilities that I can think of 1) the cookie was not deleted, 2) the cookie was deleted, but the the running javascript wrote it again, 3) the restored page makes a request that results in a response containing a Set-Cookie header that restores it. I'd look at the network tab in your debug panel and see which request is the first one that contains a Cookie header containing that cookie. That may help pinpoint the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpCookie httpCookie = default(HttpCookie);
int i = 0;
string cookieName = null;
int limit = Request.Cookies.Count - 1;
for (i = 0; i <= limit; i++) 
{
     cookieName = Request.Cookies(i).Name;     
     httpCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);    
     httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
     Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
}
```

Comment: Hi...Deleting a cookie that is physically removing it from the user's hard disk is tricky. You cannot directly remove a cookie because the cookie is on the user's computer. However, you can have the browser delete the cookie for you. The technique is to create a new cookie with the same name as the cookie to be deleted, but to set the cookie's expiration to a date earlier than today. When the browser checks the cookie's expiration, the browser will discard the now-outdated cookie. The above code shows one way to delete all the cookies available to the application:

Comment: @AmanKedia Thats what i am doing right now. Please check `clearCookies` function. It basically does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You use below code and change the cookie name if it is different:

```
Set-Cookie "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0=deleted;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there can be many solutions to this.

According to my perception, the best would be to expire the JWT Access token on the server-side if possible.

Another solution can be to disable the back button using javascript.
you can use something like:

```
(function (global) { 
    if(typeof (global) === "undefined") {throw new Error("undefined window")}
    global.onhashchange = function () {
        if (global.location.hash !== hs) {
            global.location.hash = hs;
        }
    };
    var hs = "!";
    var BackspaceBlock = function () {
        global.location.href += "#";
        global.setTimeout(function () {
            global.location.href += "!";
        }, 50);
    };
    global.onload = function () {            
        BackspaceBlock();
        document.body.onkeydown = function (e) {
            var tm = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if (e.key === 'Backspace' && (tm !== 'input' && tm !== 'password' && elm  !== 'textarea' && elm  !== 'email' && elm  !== 'url')) //other inputs in which you want backspace not disabled
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
        };          
    }
})(window);
```